# Storing 2D list from top to bottom vertically into a string

Tags: python, string, list, python-itertools

I have got a list like this:

```
[['A','B','C'], 
['D','E','F'], 
['G','H','I']]
```

Instead of storing it from left to right to string like:

```
s += s[i][j] //s = 'ABCDEFGHI'
```

How can I store it from top to bottom (vertically) to have a result like below without importing libraries or modules

```
s = 'ADGBEHCFI'
```

Answer (score 2):

First transpose the list using `zip` with **splat** operator `(*)` and then flatten it using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. Lastly join this flat iterator.

```
a = [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['G','H','I']]
In [16]: from itertools import chain
In [18]: ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(*a)))
Out[18]: 'ADGBEHCFI'
```

If you don't want to use any import modules then use this `generator` function.
see [Recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) of `itertools.from_iterable`

```
def from_iterable(iterables):
    # chain.from_iterable(['ABC', 'DEF']) --> A B C D E F
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element

In [49]: ''.join(from_iterable(zip(*a)))
Out[49]: 'ADGBEHCFI
```

Comment: @Marlon C. Carrillo check the updated answer without importing itertools.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the i and j around and you're done...

```
a = [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['G','H','I']]
s = ""
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        s += a[j][i]

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

zip it

```
>>> my_list
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']]
>>> zip(*my_list)
[('A', 'D', 'G'), ('B', 'E', 'H'), ('C', 'F', 'I')]

>>> import itertools
>>> "".join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*my_list)))
'ADGBEHCFI'
```

if you dont want to import extra module:

```
>>> "".join(map("".join,(zip(*my_list))))
'ADGBEHCFI'
```

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay check the time when i answered,

Comment: Is there any ways to do it without importing anything?

Comment: I'd imagine because your solution is pretty much identical to Vishnu's. Also that second solution, using `map`, is quite unreadable.